# Selecting and adding values found with getElementsByClassName to dict or list

Tags: javascript, html

I am very new to JavaScript and I am trying to use it to select values from HTML using `document.getElementsByClassName` by putting index [0] from `HTMLCollection`. There is either one instance of the class being present or two or more.

```
const pizzatype = document.getElementsByClassName("pizzapizza")[0].innerHTML;
const pizzacheese = document.getElementsByClassName("cheesecheese")[0].innerHTML;
const pizzasauce = document.getElementsByClassName("saucesauce")[0].innerHTML;
const ordertotal = document.getElementsByClassName("fiyat")[0].innerHTML;

const order_dict = {
  pizzatype,
  pizzacheese,
  pizzasauce,
  ordertotal
}
const s = JSON.stringify(order_dict);
console.log(s); // returns {"pizzatype":"value1","pizzacheese":"value2","pizzasauce":"value3","ordertotal":"value4"}
```

The class is set like this:

```
<div class="cheesecheese card-text">${pizza.cheese}</div>
```

I tried experimenting with for loop, `index()`, `.length`, and others but I never got it to work. What would be the way to go to get return:

```
{
  "pizzatype": "valuex1",
  "pizzacheese": "valuex2",
  "pizzasauce": "valuex3",
  "ordertotal": "valuex4",
  "pizzatype": "valuey1",
  "pizzacheese": "valuey2",
  "pizzasauce": "valuey3",
  "ordertotal": "valuey4"
}
```

It should work even when there are more than 2 instances of those classes.

Comment: JavaScript does not have dictionaries and lists, only Objects and Arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to store same key multiple times in Javascript object. You can use **Entries** syntax instead to get something similar.

Example of entries

```
[
 [“pizzatype”, firstval],
 [“pizzatype”, secondval],
]
```

Or you can use array of values inside your object.

To get result like so

```
{
  pizzatype: [firstval,secondval],
  …
}
```

You can get it with this way

```
{
  pizzatype: Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(“pizzapizza”)).map(elem => elem.innerHTML)
}
```